# Are there $3$ disjoint copies of $2K_{3,3} \cup (K_{5,5} \setminus C_{10})$ in $K_{11,11}$?

Tags: graph-theory

**Question**: Are there $3$ edge disjoint copies of $H:=2K_{3,3} \cup (K_{5,5} \setminus C_{10})$ in $K_{11,11}$?

Here's a drawing of $H$:

[image: $2K_{3,3} \cup (K_{5,5} \setminus C_{10})$]

I'm working on a Latin squares research problem and trying to get a construction to work.  If it would work, it would give a solution to this problem.  Only, I can't get it to work easily.  Maybe the above doesn't exist, and my construction won't work in this case.

- We see $H$ is regular with degree $3$, and the degrees of vertices in $K_{11,11}$ is $11$, so no clash there.
- $H$ has $33$ edges while $K_{11,11}$ has $121$ edges, so no clash there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I solved the other linked problem, I figured I might as well give simulated annealing a go on this one.

The answer is also yes; in fact, here, we can find $3$ disjoint copies of $2K_{3,3} \cup (K_{5,5} - P_{10})$. I added the extra edge in an attempt to make the problem a bit more constrained so that the solution would come out nicer, but I'm not sure how much of an effect it had.

The solution I found is below:

[image]

Here is my simulated annealing code (it might take a few tries before finding a zero-energy solution):

```
edges[{perm1_, perm2_}] :=
  Join[
   Tuples[{perm1[[1 ;; 3]], perm2[[1 ;; 3]]}],
   Tuples[{perm1[[4 ;; 6]], perm2[[4 ;; 6]]}],
   Complement[
    Tuples[{perm1[[7 ;; 11]], perm2[[7 ;; 11]]}],
    Table[{perm1[[i]], perm2[[i]]}, {i, 7, 11}],
    Table[{perm1[[i]], perm2[[i + 1]]}, {i, 7, 10}]]];
value[state_] := 102 - Length[Union @@ (edges /@ state)];
randomPerm[] := {RandomSample[Range[11]], RandomSample[Range[11]]}
newState[] := {{Range[11], Range[11]}, randomPerm[], randomPerm[]};
randomSwitch[state_] := 
 Module[{h = RandomInteger[{2, 3}], i = RandomInteger[{1, 2}], j, k, 
   copy = state},
  {j, k} = RandomSample[Range[11], 2];
  copy[[h, i, {j, k}]] = Reverse[copy[[h, i, {j, k}]]];
  Return[copy];
  ]

currentState = bestState = newState[];
currentEnergy = bestEnergy = value[currentState];
temp = 1;
While[Exp[-1/temp] > 1/1000,
 Do[
  nextState = randomSwitch[currentState];
  nextEnergy = value[nextState];
  If[nextEnergy < bestEnergy, bestState = nextState; 
   bestEnergy = nextEnergy];
  prob = Exp[-((nextEnergy - currentEnergy)/temp)];
  If[RandomReal[] < prob, currentState = nextState; 
   currentEnergy = nextEnergy];
  , {3000}];
 If[bestEnergy == 0, Break[]];
 temp *= 0.99; Print[{temp, currentEnergy}]
 ]
Print["Done ", bestEnergy];
```